# Magento 2.0 front end directory empty!

Tags: magento2, frontend

I just installed Magento 2, now I am trying to change the front end but when I try to look for the files in app/design/frontend/ (as all tutorials say) the directory is empty. 
Can anyone help or guide me please?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All themes loaded via composer are installed in the vendor directory, this changed during one of the Magento 2 beta's. You can find the Magento Blank and the Magento Luma theme in /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank and /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma.